# Changing the arrow icon of "Select"

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown, antd

I want to replace the default dropdown select arrow with and icon provided by ant design (https://ant.design/components/icon/), for example the DownCircleOutlined. Is it possible? This is my current code. I do not have any styles for it yet as I do not know the approach.

```
<Select>
    <Option value="1">a</Option>
    <Option value="2">b</Option>
    <Option value="3">c</Option>
</Select>
```

Comment: The `Select` component of Ant Design actually seems to allow you to implement custom icon by passing the Icon component to the corresponding prop. https://ant.design/components/select/#Select-props

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `suffixIcon` prop on the `Select` component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-ant-design-demo-k217c?file=/index.js:0-679

Like so:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import './index.css'
import { Select } from 'antd'
import { DownCircleTwoTone } from '@ant-design/icons'
const { Option } = Select

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select
    suffixIcon={<DownCircleTwoTone />}
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
  >
    <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
    <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
    <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
  </Select>,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

Comment: suffixIcon onclick doesn't open up a dropdown, any fix?

Comment: @TechticSolutionsInc add `className="ant-select-suffix"` to your component

Comment: How to modify its color?

Comment: @ChervinTanilon

Give `DownCircleTwoTone` a className. Inspect the element. You will see the html structure of the icon should be:
`.CLASSNAMEGIVEN` > `svg` > `path`, `path`, `path` (3 sibling path elements)

You will need to target each sibling with a pseudo selector such as  `nth-child()` and change the `fill` property of the `path` elements to modify the icon color.